# Rotateleft array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am trying to rotate the array by using following function:

```
def rotLeft(a,d):
    temp=[]
    temp.append(a[0:-1])
    temp.insert(0,a[-1])
    return temp
```

I should get output as 5 1 2 3 4

but I am getting 5,[1,2,3,4]

how to solve this problem

Comment: what is `d`? in your fnc

Comment: No need for `temp`, just do `return a[-1:] + a[0:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You must use Use `.extend()` instead of `.append()` as `.append()` and `.insert()` is for adding elements while `.extend()` is to merge two lists:

```
def rotLeft(a,d):
    temp=[]
    temp.extend(a[0:-1])
    temp.insert(0,a[-1])
    return temp

print(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5], 1))
```

output:

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `temp.extend`, not `temp.append`. The latter just adds one element to `temp`, the list `[1,2,3,4]` - this is why you end up with a nested list. `extend` on the other hand works as if *each element* from `[1,2,3,4]` is appended to `temp`.